Embedding react web components: Access to script from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy
I created a react web component (r2wc/react-to-web-component). The component is hosted on vercel under https://<my-project-name>.vercel.app/assets/js/widget.js.
I try to embed the .js module via a script in a next.js project (also tried plain html) like so:
export default function Home() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://<my-project-name>.vercel.app/assets/js/widget.js';
        script.type = 'module';
        script.async = true;
        script.id = 'widget';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    
        return () => {
          document.body.removeChild(script);
        };
      }, []);

  return <widget></widget>;
};

But I get the error:
Access to script at 'https://<my-project-name>.vercel.app/assets/js/widget.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
The component is super simple and just returns a <> Hello </> tag. When I build and run locally it works perfectly fine.
I also included a vercel.json file in the app that exports the widget to make sure that CORS headers are present:
{
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/:path*",
        "destination": "/"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/assets/js/widget.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
          },
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            "value": "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS"
          },
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "value": "Content-Type" 
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "git": {
      "deploymentEnabled": {
        "master": false,
        "development": false
      }
    }
  }

What am I missing? How can I solve this?
I am now running this only in my project, a requirement would be to be able to access the widget from all origins, independently of the domain.

Open the network tab of your browser and inspect the response. Is it present at all? Is it what you expect except for the CORS headers?

Yes, as far as I can overlook this it's all there except for the CORS headers
